# Difficulty with absolute and relative paths in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have a route for an API in an Express app that looks like this:

```
app.get('/:username/:bookmark/', function(req, res) {

  // do stuff

})
```

As expected, this route resolves to:

```
GET /username/bookmark/
```

However, I would like to use relative URLs for my static resources. For example, I would like the route to my `main.css` to resolve to:

```
GET /css/main.css
```

Instead, it currently resolve to:

```
GET /username/bookmark/css/main.css
```

How can I get my app to resolve static content to `/css/main.css` and remove the leading components of the API from the URL?

Comment: I am a bit confused, might be wrong, but what is the problem with `public` folder which express use

Comment: Your given routing does trigger at `GET /username/bookmark` but it also triggers on any other route, because anything leading with `:` is just a placeholder for variables. You want to use `app.get('/username/bookmark')` to `GET /username/bookmark`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should go with `express` routing process.

Add following line to your app.js file

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

put your all `.css` files in `{approot}/public/stylesheets` folder .

and in your `HTML` files add links like following

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/index.css">
```

Answer (score 2):

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzChs.png)
source: https://github.com/mongo-express/mongo-express/pull/205

I try and it work, just add "/" before the link, example:

you are in `localhost:8080/courses/` 
and your href is: `href="style/style.css"`
you will lead to `localhost:8080/courses/style/style.css.`

solution is add"/" before, example: `href="/style/style.css"` 
 it will start from root " `localhost:8080/style/style.css"`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a concrete example, take the typical use-case of serving files in ./public using the express.static() middleware:

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

Comment: Thanks, yes I am already doing this. I still get the behaviour I outlined above.

Answer (score 1):

If you're at `/username/bookmark/` and you link the CSS like this

```
<link href="css/main.css" />
```

or this

```
<link href="./css/main.css" />
```

It will resolve to `/username/bookmark/css/main.css`. But you want to link in like this

```
<link href="/css/main.css" />
```

The problem is, that the `.static`-middleware only routes at the base path `/` instead of all routes you defined.

Answer (score 1):

When using try:

```
app.get("/:username/:bookmark/", function(req, res) {});
```

With the `:` you  do not state which path you get, but it will get all paths and you know what the path is if you type `req.params.username` or `req.params.bookmark`.  If you want the path to `/username/bookmark/` you must do this:

```
app.get("/username/bookmark/", function() {});
    //Do something
});
```