# Express - static file being served cannot be located

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to serve static files (CSS stylesheets) with Express, and it is located when I am on some routes such as the home page `/` or index page `/index`. However, when I navigate to a `/index/:id` page, I get this error in the chrome console:

`GET http://localhost:3000/index/stylesheets/styles.css net::ERR_ABORTED`

I'm sure that the reason why I am getting this error is because the css file is not actually served in the location stated in the error. I verified that the actual location that it is being served is `http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/styles.css`.

I have this following line of code in my server file: to serve the css file `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));`

and this is the code for the `/index/:id` route:

```
app.get('/index/:id', function(req, res) {
  Post.findById({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, foundPost){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect('/');
    }
    else {
      res.render('./index/show', {post: foundPost});
    }
  });
});
```

and I made sure to add the CSS to every html page being served with this exact line: 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/styles.css" />`

Why is the CSS included for routes such as `/` or `/index`, but looks in the wrong place for it when I navigate to a `/index/:id` page? The location that the page is looking for the css file in changes from `http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/styles.css` to `http://localhost:3000/index/stylesheets/styles.css` depending on the route I am on.

What am I missing? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24737773/difficulty-with-absolute-and-relative-paths-in-express

Comment: @user-developer thank you! adding the extra `/` before `stylesheets/styles.css` did the trick... which makes sense because without it, it would just try to look for the css file in the local folder...

Answer (score 0):

This works for me-

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```