# a href not linking in same folder

Tags: html

I am getting an error from a link in my html code, the following should suffice an explanation.

Folder Structure

```
html    
  entry.html
  admin.html
```

entry.html:
`<a href="admin.html">ADMIN</a>`

ERROR: `Cannot GET /admin.html`

Folder Structure

```
public
  admin.html
  html
    entry.html
```

entry.html: `<a href="../admin.html">ADMIN</a>`

SUCCESS

Follows is the code for the node server

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  if (userIsLoggedIn()) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/html/entry.html');
  } else {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/accessDenied.html');
  }
});

function userIsLoggedIn() {
  return true;
}

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use('/html', express.static(__dirname + '/public/html'));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/public/css'));
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/public/js'));
app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname + '/public/images'));

var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("Server started at http://localhost:%s", port);
});
```

Comment: I think your problem is same the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24737773/difficulty-with-absolute-and-relative-paths-in-express

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href = “./admin.html”> ADMIN </a>
```

The above line should work when in the same folder.

If that doesn’t work there is an error in some other part of the code.

Comment: Added the express code, I am guessing this is where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/entry.html');

app.use('/html', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

I think this should work. You are referring to this not working ?